# Unable to access user's username using Facebook api 2.0

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am using `facebook api 2.0` to allow users to use their Facebook profile data to fill up my custom form. (I don't want facebook's prefilled form). I am getting other information like first name, last name, email. But apparently Facebook api 2.0 has removed username from response object and I am unable to access it. I have observed that Response.link contains url of the person's profile and the portion after `"www.facebook.com/"` is identical to username. If we succeed in fetching link, we could get Username. But I am not sure this is true for all users. However when i try to access the link, I get link with app scoped id like this:

```
"www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/XXXXXX/"
```

where last portion (XXXXXX) is some numerical id. Does anybody know how to access the link in the form of "https://www.facebook.com/username"?

Also, if we are not able to do that in 2.0 but we can in 1.0, then how to switch back to 1.0?

Comment: Do you want to get current authorized user's username only OR any user?

Comment: Current authorized user's username. When he visits page, he will get option, something like "Signup with Facebook". When he clicks it, he will get chance to authenticate himself using Facebook login dialog. After successful login I want to access his username.

Comment: Once you have pushed v2.0 to production, and real users have connected with it, you will have issues switching back to v1.0, as `/user` calls involving these users will be interpreted as v2.0 no matter what version you specify. There are some gotchas here, and I found them confusing too, so I wrote a [blog post](http://code-worrier.com/blog/changes-in-facebook-graph-api-2-dot-0/) explaining them.

Answer (score 4):

As https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_api_versions is clearly stating

> /me/username is no longer available

If your app is created after April 30th 2014, there's no way switching back to v1.0. If not, you can prepend `/v1.0` to your request, but that will only work until April 30th, 2015.

Comment: Well, then your app is created after April 30th 2014. I see no chance that you can get the `username`. Anyway, why do you specifically need this? Can't you use the `user_id` for example?

Comment: It would help me if I fill my username field with user's Facebook username whereas user id is numerical and difficult to remember. e.g. johnbrown is easier to remember than 452864562822 for example. Also Facebook username would be unique.

Comment: Then use a concatination of `first_name` and `last_name` for example. Don't see a problem here... It's a fact that you can't get the `username` anymore, so I recommend that you try to find another suiting solution, instead of trying to get some workaround which will be invalid anyway next year

Comment: If we are able to access the link property, we could get username. Unfortunately I am getting link with scoped id as mentioned in my question.

Comment: I think this is useless. Create a clean solution, not a workaround.

Comment: It is no longer possible to get the username field via API v2.0 by any means.

In Graph API v2.0, Facebook moved to app-scoped user IDs to help protect people's information. A username is a globally unique field, being able to access the username field would invalidate the point of moving to app-scoped IDs.

If you want to pre-fill a form, I suggest making your own username algorithm based on the user's first and last names.

Answer (score 2):

If you only require current authorized user's username(or any other authorized user for your app), then it's possible.

First step, you call **/v2.0/me?fields=third_party_id** endpoint . You have to use authorized User Access Token (Authorized with basic scope, i.e. **public_profile** permission enough).

[image]

Or alternative way, you can use App Access Token instead. Of course you can't use **me** connection anymore, you have to explicitly to put User ID. For example, **12345678** shown on the folowing screenshot:

[image]

Second step, use App Access Token (User Access Token is not allow here) to call following FQL query:

> SELECT username FROM standard_user_info WHERE third_party_id =
>   'example12345abcdef'

In which "example12345abcdef" is the **third_party_id** example you get from the first step.

[image]

**p/s**: please note that the user/app access token on first step must use the **same app** on second step. It's because third_party_id is tied to app.

Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Unfortunately I would not be able to user server side code to obtain App Access token.

Comment: FQL is deprecated after v2.1 :/

Answer (score 2):

Note that `username` is optional on Facebook. By default a Facebook profile doesn't have a username

[image]

In any Facebook API response, you'll get the username, only if the user has set his username under his Facebook settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to show the user his name why not use the "name" field? It contains their first and last name both. I have changed my app to use name instead of "username".