# No username returned in facebook profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I just re-registered our facebook app on developers.facebook.com, got the app id and secret. So far so good.

Now when I get the user profile with the new appId and appSecret, the username field is null, where as other fields like lastName etc. are set (I do `UserProfile userProfile = connection.fetchUserProfile()` with spring-social-facebook).

I'm sure that the username field has been filled out previously with the old appId. I can't find out why the username now is not sent by facebook anymore. We need the username to locally store the user if he's logging in with facebook.

Is this a setting on the facebook app settings page that I'm missing? Or did something change on facebook's side?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670557/unable-to-access-users-username-using-facebook-api-2-0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've registered your app with Facebook since April 30th, then you're working against Facebook's v2.0 API (no choice...Facebook enforces it for apps registered after April 30th). In v2.0, there is no username. It's simply not available anymore.

Apps registered prior to April 30th will default to v1.0, but you can request v2.0. As it stands right now, however, Spring Social Facebook is coded against v1.0. If you try to use it against v2.0, then most things will still work, but some things won't (usernames, for example. Also, getting a list of friends will only return friends who have also authorized the same application.)

I'm working to update Spring Social Facebook's API to work against v2.0, but it's a non-trivial task. I hope to complete the work soon, though.

Comment: That sounds promising, thanks. I used the FB username to store a human readable username for the user in the local DB when he's using "Login with facebook". I now have to find a way how to make the local username "unique".

Comment: If you're just looking for some String value to uniquely identify the user, the user ID from Facebook should work. Historically, the user ID is always the best way to uniquely identify the user, because (among other reasons) it can't be changed. Going forward (FB API 2.0) the FB user ID will be unique per application, but the same FB user may have a different user ID in a different application. As long as you don't maintain 2 or more apps and need to associate users between them, the user ID is still a solid choice for a unique identifier.

Comment: Even if you *do* maintain more than one app and need to associate users across all of those apps, there is a mechanism for doing that with FB API 2.0 with the "Business Mapping API)...but honestly I've not had an opportunity to experiment with that yet.